# Filling multiple missing data with EM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, probability

I'm studying with [this ppt](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-825-techniques-in-artificial-intelligence-sma-5504-fall-2002/lecture-notes/Lecture18FinalPart1.pdf). Starting from page 22, it's showing how a missing data can be filled with the most likely value with EM algorithm. I managed to understand this but I started wondering how I can fill 2 missing data. If 2 data only in field B were missing, I can see how I would calculate it. But what if one data is missing, both in A and B field? The calculation on the ppt is being conducted with the assumption that data on A is firm but in this case it's not... Can someone explain a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want missing values on both A and B, you need some additional hidden variables.
To be more precise:

Assume that you have 4 hidden variables, H1, H2, A' and B' taking values in {0, 1} which generates your observations (A, B) as follows:

- A = A' if H1=0, A = 'H' otherwise
- B = B' if H1=0, B = 'H' otherwise

and assume that (A', B') is independent from (H1, H2). Therefore, your model is parametrized by the joint distribution of (A', B') and the joint distribution of (H1, H2).

Now to learn the model, you can just run EM as you did before, the only difference is that your hidden variable H is now extended by A', B', H1 and H2. Once your model is learnt, you can fill the missing pairs of observations by the most likely pair (given the distribution of the model).